# SQL QUERY SSRS REPORT

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I am using two tablix in SSRS report. In one I have used data group by month name in column group shows like below:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| jan | feb | mar |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 100 | 200 | 300 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

And I need to show same data into another tablix. How can I put data from one tablix to second one? The problem is that it is created dynamically from column grouping.

Thanks

Comment: If you want data from one tablix in another on the same report.. does that not imply that you are using the same dataset? In which case.. summarise the second tablix to suit using the same dataset.. if that does not suit.. show us screen shots of what ever to illustrate your issue and we may be able to help!

Comment: Hi Harry I am using different data sets for both. That is the issue

Comment: You'll need to show examples of the output from the datasets. There is not enough info to help you at the moment. Also describe where eh data from each dataset comes from, do they comes from teh same database, is it possible to combine the data from both queries into a single dataset etc?

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for Reporting Services [nesting data regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/nested-data-regions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)